# DOM element creator

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create a function using vanilla JS that will:

1. Create a new DOM element
2. Assign it a Class Name
3. Place it in the DOM either appending to an existing div or inserting it specifically into the DOM if required using "insertBefore()"

I have come up with the somewhat inelegant solution below:

```
    function createDomElem(elem, className, parent, refElement, type) {
        var a = document.createElement(elem);

        if (type == "append") {
            document.querySelector(parent).appendChild(a);
        } else if (type == "insert") {
            document.querySelector(parent).parentNode.insertBefore(a, refElement)
        }
        a.className = className;
    };
```

My problems with this solution are

- Too many arguments to be passed
- If not passing "insert" then you don't require refElement and to avoid "type" being mistaken for "refElement" you'd have to pass "refElement" as "null" and then define type as "append"

So my question is where can I streamline this function to become more useful within my program?

I'm also dreaming of the ability to be able to push child divs into the newly created div right within this function, defining how many child divs you would want and then using a for loop to append or insert these. Would this be better placed in a new function though?

Comment: You want to split up the code a bit. This function is doing too many things. First, create a function that just creates the DOM node and then use other methods to append to other elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would split the code into two parts, as they have to separate *concerns*. I use something similar to the following for creating DOM elements:

```
var DomFactory = (function (document) {

    var api = {
        element: function (name, attributes) {
            var el = document.createElement(name);

            if (attributes) {
                for (var key in attributes) {
                    if (attributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        el.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
                    }
                }
            }

            return el;
        },

        div: function (attributes) {
            return api.element('div', attributes);
        }
    };

    return api;

}(window.document));
```

Usage:

```
var div = DomFactory.div({ 'class': 'hero' });
var table = DomFactory.element('table', { 'class': 'table table-bordered' });
```

Then for positioning, you could have a generalised position function:

```
function attach(source, target, position) {
  switch (position) {
    case 'before': {
      target.parentNode.insertBefore(source, target);
      break;
    }
    case 'after': {
      if (target.nextSibling) {
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(source, target.nextSibling);
      } else {
        target.parentNode.appendChild(source);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
attach(table, div, 'before');
```

Comment: I've just gotten around to adding this into my code and it's returning an Error 'undefined is not a function' when I call "var button = DomFactory.div({ 'class': 'nav-mobile' });"

Comment: Gonna need a bit more info that than that, can you paste more code, and also stack trace?

Comment: No worries Matthew, managed to get it sorted. It was because of the previous "Object.key(attributes)" inside the for...in declaration, however I see you've caught that in your edit also! Many thanks again for the help. Was extremely useful, I wonder if there is a performance gain in using this vs a solution utilising JQuery?

Comment: I dont know how much of a performance *gain* you'll get from doing raw dom vs jQuery. jQuery is pretty optimised now, and modern browsers are so performant that you'll probably not notice it. If you are doing large DOM changes, I'd isolate these in a `DocumentFragment` (which I believe jQuery does internally anyway), and then apply the fragment to the DOM instead, as then it doesn't have to worry about regenerating the shadow DOM for each individual change and then redrawing the screen.

Comment: This is a beautiful script Mathew, Thanks u!

Comment: Awesome script !